# How to add activity from Library project to the android project?

Tags: android, android-manifest, library-project

I have an android project, that uses library project. How to add the activity from the Library project to the `AndroidMAnifest.xml` of the android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the library project's activity is declaring the `Activity` with its package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` of Android project as below:

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.LibraryProjectActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Now you can access the library project's `Activity`.